# how to send json file to a restful webservice from html

Tags: html, json, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I recently started learning to create restful web services with spring framework.
all the course is using postman to send requests but I want to send requests from a web page, like creating a table and send `firstName` and `lastName` from the HTML file (from the view, .jsp file) and store it in the database.

everywhere I lookt, they all saying the standard file to send to or retrieve from a restful endpoint is JSON, not HTML.

and from what I see @RequestBody only accepts JSON or XML, not HTML inputs.

I tried sending data from HTML(Method = "POST") to a @PostMapping method of my restful web server, to create something and store it in the database but an exception that says "Content-type not supported" was thrown.

I have lots of questions about this, and they all point to the same thing, Not understanding the whole thing.

1. what's the point of creating restful web service for the back end of a website, when HTML doesn't support put and delete requests and standard file that everyone uses to get requests from the client is JSON, not HTML.
2. can a web page (HTML) generate it's content to form a JSON file that is being sent back from a restful server?
3. how can I generate a JSON file from the inputs in HTML file and send it to the restful @PostMapping method?

there are two things that I should mention here, 
I don't know much about creating web pages (HTML) I have only been creating very simple HTML files to help me create and test a back end server. 
I searched so many questions before I post this one, and none of them helped me.

Comment: use AJAX for sending json data to server side. first prepare JSON object using JS or Jquery. then send that object with help of POST.

Comment: use this link to know complete idea about RESTFul  [click here](https://www.java4s.com/web-services/what-is-web-services-web-services-introduction/)

Comment: @KKishoreKumarReddy thanks for the link, it was amazing, however, I kind of knew them as I have a very good rest course.

Comment: @KKishoreKumarReddy so preparing a json file and sending them to server using ajax, js and jquery is something that people normally do for sending json files to restful controllers ? is it work like how postman works ? because i want to know about the standard way of sending sending json files from web page to rest server

Comment: you can use  JSON Server to design frontend Restful API. use this link for [JSONServer](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d) flow.   You can also use RestTemplate Class for Restful Testing, but this is at backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions

First, you need to understand what rest is it is a **Representational state transfer (REST) is a software architectural style that defines a set of constraints to be used for creating Web services.**(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) 
so we follow a set of standards to make things easier.

Now coming to your actual question why JSON and not HTML because these are not only consumed from HTML these are consumed by different apps or services and json is a more lightweight and less verbose format, and it’s easier to read and write as well. In most cases, it’s ideal for data interchange over the internet
and we can use it with front end libraries like react , jquery or vanilla javascript to render the content in HTML from JSON without any changes to the API and also use a Backend web service to use this API.

**https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/**
**https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html**

for the other two questions basically You don't have to generate JSON file to call the rest API from HTML and render the content in HTML Instead you can use front end libraries like Jquery, React, Angular or use vanilla javascript to render content and call the rest API.

Comment: not all heroes wear capes.
thank you, this is the **best answer** i could receive.